# Mongodb export nested field

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I have a MongoDB and I want to export to a .csv file.

document:

```
{
  "id" : 28,
  "organisation" : "Mickey Mouse company",
  "country" : "US",
  "contactpersons" : [{
      "title" : "",
      "typecontact" : "D",
      "mobilenumber" : "757784854",
      "firstname" : "Mickey",
      "lastname" : "Mouse",
      "emailaddress" : "mickey@mouse.com"
    }],
  "modifieddate" : "2013-11-21T16:04:49+0100"
}
```

I want to export all document and only want the field contactpersons.firstname and contactpersons.emailaddress

I use this commandline:

```
     mongoexport -o /tmp/export.csv -host dbmongo -port 27017 -db organisation -collection organisationa -u user -p password -csv  -fields 'contactpersons.0.firstname, contactpersons.0.emailaddress'
```

This works more or less, it exports but only exports the field firstname and not emailaddress. I need it also the export the field emailaddress.

Any idea how I can do this? I don't understand why it doesn't work even though I do give the  emailaddress field. Do error is given.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Double quotes worked perfectly for me anywway, mongoexport -o export.csv -db stackoverflow -collection exportcsv -fields "contactpersons.0.firstname, contactpersons.0.emailaddress" --csv

Answer (score 13):

Found it. I needed to remove the spaces.

This is wrong:

```
mongoexport -o /tmp/export.csv -host dbmongo -port 27017 -db organisation -collection organisationa -u user -p password -csv  -fields 'contactpersons.0.firstname, contactpersons.0.emailaddress'
```

This is correct:

```
mongoexport -o /tmp/export.csv -host dbmongo -port 27017 -db organisation -collection organisationa -u user -p password -csv  -fields 'contactpersons.0.firstname,contactpersons.0.emailaddress'
```

Comment: will it export both documents Mickey and Donald both in separate rows?

Answer (score 8):

Create fields.txt file and insert the following fields into it :

```
contactpersons.0.firstname
contactpersons.0.emailaddress
```

Then you can use the following command to export given fields into .csv

```
mongoexport -d organisation -c organisation -fieldFile fields.txt --csv > /tmp/export.csv
```

Comment: Need a little more info, what if I want to export multiple documents from the `contactpersons` array? For instance, I have document like this `{
  "id" : 28,
  "organisation" : "ABC company",
  "country" : "US",
  "contactpersons" : [{
      "title" : "",
      "firstname" : "Mickey",
      "lastname" : "Mouse",
      "emailaddress" : "mickey@mouse.com"
    },{
      "title" : "",
      "firstname" : "Donald",
      "lastname" : "Duck",
      "emailaddress" : "donal@duck.com"
    }],
  "modifieddate" : "2013-11-21T16:04:49+0100"
}` Need to export both the objects in the `contactpersons` array.

Comment: @AyazPasha Did you find any solution to export a document with an array which may content more than one element at the end?